# Анимация градиента?

Tags: html, css, анимация

Всем доброго времени суток, может кто разбирается, никак не могу анимировать градиент, хочу чтобы он переливался бесконечно, сейчас он у меня дергается

https://jsfiddle.net/1h8pzwmt/1/

```
<div class="preloader"></div>

.preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 44%;
    height: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(270deg, #000, #fff, #000, #fff);
    animation: gradient 0.8s linear 2s infinite;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: -100px 0;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 120% 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 180% 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: animation: gradient 5s ease infinite;

Comment: @Arcadiy, и чем же это лучше linear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #000, #fff, #000, #fff, #000);
  animation: gradient 0.8s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  from { background-position:    0   0; }
  to   { background-position:  300px 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader"></div>
```

Comment: Забавно выглядит (+)